# I am doing a post request where I want to type in a question and with the post request get the most common answer

Tags: swift, post, request

I have done my Post-request but I am unsure about how to make it possible to send a full question and to get the most common answers back to my app.

I am in such a big need of this code in my program so would love to get some examples on how to make it work

Have tried to right the question into the parameters with a "+" instead of space which resulted into nothing.

```
 @IBAction func GetAnswer(_ sender: Any) {

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.google.com/search?q=");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = questionAsked;
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {

                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let answer = parseJSON[" Answer "] as? String
                    self.AnswerView.text = ("Anwer: \(String(describing: answer))")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: For an example, "How old is George Bush?"

Comment: This kind of searching is best done by querying a supported JSON API. Check out: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list, and use a custom sort parameter to rank the best results.

Comment: Thank you @PranavKasetti. I will take a look into it

Comment: But I can not find any information of how to write it in code that I need in my app. Do you know where I can see or do you know how to? @PranavKasetti

Comment: The same code you have should still work, use URLSession and check what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `google.com/search`, please check the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Paste following in Playground, should give a good start

```
struct Constants {
    static let apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    static let bundleId = "YOUR_IOS_APP_BUNDLE_ID"
    static let searchEngineId = "YOUR_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID"
}

func googleSearch(term: String, callback:@escaping ([(title: String, url: String)]?) -> Void) {
    let urlString = String(format: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=%@&cx=%@&key=%@", term, Constants.searchEngineId, Constants.apiKey)
    let encodedUrl = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    guard let url = URL(string: encodedUrl ?? urlString) else {
        print("invalid url \(urlString)")
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(Constants.bundleId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let datatask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]
        else {
            // error handing here
            callback(nil)
            return
        }

        guard let items = json["items"] as? [[String : Any]], items.count > 0 else {
            print("no results")
            return
        }

        callback(items.map { ($0["title"] as! String, $0["formattedUrl"] as! String) })
    }

    datatask.resume()
}
```

**Usage**

```
googleSearch(term: "George Bush") { results in
    print(results ?? [])
}
```

Create a new search engine using following url

```
https://cse.google.com/cse/create/new
```

If you would like search entire web, use following steps

1. edit your engine using `https://cse.google.com/cse/setup/basic?cx=SEARCH_ENGINE_ID`
2. remove any pages listed under **Sites to search**
3. turn on **Search the entire web**